# How to combine subscription values

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

```
of(1,2,3).subscribe((no) =>{
    console.log(no);
  })
```

Output:
1
2
3
But I need output as an array of [1,2,3]

Comment: use a forkjoin forkjoin(...,...,..).subscribe(x => { console.log(x[1], x[2], x[3])})

Answer (score 4):

Use [`toArray`](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/toArray/)

```
of(1,2,3).pipe(toArray()).subscribe((no) =>{
    console.log(no);
  });
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-b1dbsg)

Comment: I my case I'm getting output as

Comment: 1 12 123 if I use to array() I'm getting [1,12,123]

Comment: @ShivaSai - then you are doing something other than what I posted above or what you said you were doing in your question. See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-b1dbsg) I had included in may answer, that produces the expected result.

Comment: Yes I'm subscribed to actionsSubj which returns the completed actions one by one

Comment: @ShivaSai - Update your [mcve] accordingly in your question (use the edit link).

Answer (score 0):

```
import { reduce } from 'rxjs/operators';

of(1, 2, 3).pipe(
    reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur], [])
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: Please don't provide code-only answers, but include relevant information explaining your code.